# expression "that would have been a monumental moment!", correct?

Tags: expressions, historical-change

A famous person in the field said to me "I met this popular guy xx in a conference" I wanted to respond by saying "you two gurus met? that would have been a monumental moment"

does this grammatically make sense?

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not quite. There are two words that are frequently confused even by native speakers - *momentous* and *monumental*. You want the former here - *a momentous occasion.* (But please, not [monumentous](https://mycitymusings.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/words-words-words-monumentous/), not yet, anyway.

Comment: I would also recommend saying, “That ***must have been*** ...” instead of “that would have been” since the meeting actually did occur.

Comment: Monumental -  "Great in importance, extent, or size." Oxford Dictionary online

Comment: Jim and Clare, thanks so much! this is super helpful!